# I want to add dynamic fields in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using MongoDB(Mongoose), Node(Express), React.

I want to create this functionality: Create Collections. In these collections create products corresponding to these collections. For example a book collection.

The collection should have mandatory fields: `id`, `title`, `description`.
The product should also have mandatory fields, as well as additional fields that will be added at the collection creation level, that is, when creating a collection we should be able to add additional fields for future products that will be created in it.

**My CollectionModel:**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


const CollectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        creator: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },

        additionalFields: {},

        items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);


export default mongoose.model('Collections', CollectionSchema);
```

**My ItemModel:**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        
    },

    { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model('Collections', UserSchema);
```

How to do this with mongoose and express?

I wanted to find a library to create dynamic schemas in mongoose, but failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Creating "dynamic schemas" does not really seem to fit the MongoDB spirit. In fact MongoDB doesn't support any kind of schema, Mongoose does ! And as they are defined in code, they're not very dynamic.

It seems to me that you are looking for the mongoose [strict option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) (enabled by default)
**It can be disabled**. Which lets you save any field in the DB, even those not defined in the model. You'll loose mongoose control over those fields though (type/value checking, defaults, relations, etc).